# Azure Data Factory - Import excel file with dynamic range2

Tags: excel, azure-data-factory

I have a scenario where I'm converting Excel to CSV/TXT my excel file is formatted,which means main content starts at let's say A12 but end cell is dynamic( like Y400 or y700 etc..) that we don't know, in that case is there a possibility in ADF to define Excel range.

Answer (score 0):

There is a range option in adf for excel dataset wherein you can mention the dynamic range as below:

A12

This would start from A12 and dynamically locate the end point

range   :-
The cell range in the given worksheet to locate the selective data, e.g.:

- Not specified: reads the whole worksheet as a table from the first non-empty row and column
- A3: reads a table starting from the given cell, dynamically detects all the rows below and all the columns to the right
- A3:H5: reads this fixed range as a table
- A3:A3: reads this single cell

Comment: My excel file is formatted excel that has actual data, that I want to export to csv is from A14 to A171
When I define Range as A14 it's reading empty rows as well   "rowsRead": 24277,
    "rowsCopied": 24277,
{
    "dataRead": 122880,
    "dataWritten": 1943751,
    "filesRead": 1,
    "filesWritten": 1,
    "sourcePeakConnections": 1,
    "sinkPeakConnections": 1,
    "rowsRead": 24277,
    "rowsCopied": 24277,
    "copyDuration": 8,
    "throughput": 15,

Comment: Hey, Unfortunately that's the case w.r.t dynamic range wherein it is ideally preferred to have only actual rows and clear out the empty rows. Other way would be to have a custom logic to get the end count and pass it as value in range in dataset

Comment: Thanks for the inputs,when you suggest 'Custom Logic' could you guide what type of custom logic,is it use a Azure function or something?

Answer (score 0):

Use a DataFlow and follow the below steps:

1.Add your excel/CSV Source data set( Insert 'FileName' in column to save filename
2. add filter activity and insert 'length(trim(replace(trim(replace(replace(replace(replace(replace( toString(array(columns())  ),'null','' ), ',',''),FileName,''),'[',''),']','')),'""',''))) !=  0'
3. Boom!! empty rows are gone.